# C# What parameter does my object need?

Tags: c#

sorry if this is an too easy one, but I am confused:

I need to build a new object in my class like that:

```
    MockTheLocation MockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this);
```

If I were to do this in within any function of that class, I could do this:

```
var MockingObject = new MocktheLocation(this);
```

but since I am doing this outside of any class I cannot use var. 
Now, that I used the correct type (MockTheLocation), Visual Studio tells me, I cannot use "this" anymore. It stats that the "this" keyword is not available in the current context.

The "MockTheLocation" Class has this constructor:

```
private Context ctxt;

//Konstruktor 
public MockTheLocation(Context cxt)
{
    this.ctxt = cxt;

}
```

I need to hand over this context, in oder to call the locationmanger here:

```
        var mLocationManager = ctxt.GetSystemService(Context.LocationService) as LocationManager;
```

So what exactly do I need to fill in into the new MockTheLocation(this) part?
I hope this is not too hard to understand :)

THANKS!

Comment: "but since I am doing this outside of any class" - then where *are* you doing it? You haven't given us enough context about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `"since I am doing this outside of any class"` - ... Then where *are* you doing this?  Show a more complete code sample.  If you're trying to declare variables *outside of a class* then that isn't going to work at all, regardless of what mix of keywords you try to use.  All code statements have to be in class structures of some kind.

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to declare this as a class-level member?  If so then I suspect you can't use `this` because at that time the instance hasn't been constructed yet.  Alternatively you can declare the variable at the class level and instantiate it (with `this`) in the constructor.

Comment: Im doing that globally right under the namespace of the class

Comment: @MrMee: Then you can't do that.  Variables can't exist outside of a class.  (What exactly would you expect `this` to refer to if you're not in a class?)

Comment: damnit... thanks tho...

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you try to use  `this` in a scope where it doesn't exist eg.

```
class Context
{
    MockTheLocation MockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this); //<<- you can't use 'this' here
}
```

Instead create the MockingObject in the constructor of the `Context` object:

```
class Context
{
    MockTheLocation MockingObject;
    public Context()
    {
        MockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this); // 'this' is know in this scope
    }
}
```